# Relative paths not working in model builder

Tags: arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, file-path

I checked "Store relative path names" in my model, but ArcGIS seems to ignore the settings - the paths are always the same as on my computer.
Plus, the "Store relative path names" unchecks automatically sometimes (I didn't find what triggers it).

How to ensure the relative paths are used? Why does ArcGIS ignore the "Store relative path names" option?

Comment: I've found that this setting is very inconsistent in ModelBuilder. I always check it by default, because I have found that if I don't check it, my model will fall apart if I move it, even if I have cleared any path references in the tools. Having it checked on limits that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have come across the same issue, here is how I could manage it:

1. Check: Store relative path names.
2. In environment settings, set the current workspace as the folder you placed your toolbox in.
3. Having these two features set, toolbox will trigger its location wherever it is copied.
4. Replace your static paths initials with "%workspace%".
5. Test by moving the toolbox to an other directory in you machine

Comment: Have you confirmed it works when the Hard Drive letter change? If it does, I will gladly upvote and accept your answer, even though I no longer have this problem or even ArcGIS 10.1. Otherwise, Alex's answer would be right.

Comment: Yes Mr. Pavel, I have confirmed my answer by copying model between C, D, E and found tool works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe relative pathnames do not work in Model Builder when the Hard Drive letter changes (or across Hard Drives). Also, try setting your Output/Data-Paths to a subfolder from where the toolbox/script resides.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable > workspace and set the path to your gdb. Rename it "MyWorkSpace" or something, then you can use %MyWorkSpace% to create the paths to any input data that you would otherwise drag in.