# Calling Python script tool from ArcGIS model using relative path?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, python-script-tool, file-path

I am new to ArcGIS and facing a problem in calling a script tool from a model.

I have the following file structure:

- E:\MyFolder

  - MyToolbox.tbx

    - ScriptTool
    - Model
  - Scripts

    - myscript.py

The ScriptTool uses 'E:\Scripts\myscript.py' as the script file and is configured to use relative path. Hence, even if I move MyFolder from E:\ to D:\ , the ScriptTool is able to find myscript.py and it executes successfully.

Also the ScriptTool is added to the Model. The Model works fine if MyFolder is in E:\ but if I move MyFolder to D:\ , the Model cannot run as it is not able to find the ScriptTool.

Please help me by suggesting how I can add the ScriptTool to the Model such that the model uses relative paths to the script tool.

Comment: Possibly related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54977/relative-paths-not-working-in-model-builder

Comment: This is an old and long document from the 9.3 Help but it *may* explain what is going on: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Pathnames_explained:_Absolute,_relative,_UNC,_and_URL  I've had a long day so am not keen to try and explain it but if the link does not help you perhaps someone else can.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [old and long document from the 9.3 Help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Pathnames_explained:_Absolute,_relative,_UNC,_and_URL) solved my problem.

On right clicking the model and opening the properties, there was the option to use relative paths.